# Is there a real code-free webpage design tool?

Tags: software-rec, website

Recently I was doing web design. I found that the current web design tool (like Expression Web, Dreamweaver) is terribly coupled with code. Though I managed to use HTML, CSS and many others, I found those tool not free enough when came to design. What I want is a totaly code-free design tool with which I can use to draw the layout, paste pictures, add texts and so on. **It doesn't need to have functionality to covert the design into code because I can do it myself**. That is to say, **I need the software to create a blueprint for me**. I'm currently using Photoshop to do this. However it is too stupid in displying the layout (It can't show the width and many other attributes, I had to draw them by myself). Can you find one for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/22813/web-based-diagramming-and-mock-up-screen-applications http://superuser.com/questions/33442/software-for-designing-prototypes-a-raw-design-of-user-interfaces

Comment: Probably picky, but Expression Web and Dreamweaver aren't webpage design tools, they're WYSIWYG webpage editors - they're MEANT to use code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me that what you would really benefit from is a mockup or wireframe type application to get your design ideas off the ground. [This article](http://speckyboy.com/2010/01/11/10-completely-free-wireframe-and-mockup-applications/) has a nice list of free options out there.

Comment: Also, I found a plugin for Illusion(R) named CADTool. It satisfies me the most.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, id strongly recommend learning at least basic html and css if your doing anything with websites. It can save you many hours of headaches when trying to work out why things arent doign what you expect them to do and it will, eventually, make you a much better web designer.

However, in answer to your question, why dont you try xara web designer. From what ive heard its about the simplest wysiwyg tool around. Its not free, but it does have a 30 day trial, so it cant hurt to try:
http://www.xara.com/us/downloads/webdesigner/. Hope this helps.

Comment: "It doesn't need to have functionality to covert the design into code because I can do it myself."

Answer (score 0):

For web WYSIWYG tools, one of the best I know of is still [Net Objects Fusion](http://netobjects.com/html/fusion_11.html).  It's not free, and it'll still generate code, but it does a lot of layout customization very easily and then you can decide to use it's code, or you can re-do in your favorite package. However, if all you need is a layout design tool, why not a desktop publishing application like MS Publisher?  Does the same thing, just no HTML code behind it.